# Canvas - Fade out case

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm using canvas to generate random colored objects with an interval. What I want to do is, to fade the objects into whiteness just like they're fading into fog.

I want to achieve this without needing to redraw every object in every frame. Instead, I'm putting white layers between objects (with small opacity) so that it gives the efect of fade out.

Here is my current approach:
http://jsfiddle.net/zettam/pUVkA/26/

```
var cvas = document.getElementById("ctxt");
var cx = cvas.getContext("2d");

function randomColor(num) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
}

setInterval(function() {
    var r = randomColor(255);
    var g = randomColor(255);
    var b = randomColor(255);
    cx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ",1.0)";
    cx.fillRect(200*Math.random(), 200*Math.random(), 300*Math.random(), 300*Math.random());
}, 200);

setInterval(function() {
    cx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.025)"
    cx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
}, 20);​
```

Asyou can see, the objects never fade out to fully white, but instead, they stay at somewhere gray.

How can I achieve what I need without having to re-draw everything every frame ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The opacity setting in `cx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.025)"` is not working when less than `0.1`. (some calculation problem with that function?)

Try setting it to `0.1` instead of `0.025` and change the Interval to something higher to compensate like `50` ?

Comment: but then the fade out becomes so fast. I want a subtle fading.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/pUVkA/31/

It's a compromise between the two methods. As @Josh mentioned, the canvas compositing code has a problem with completely overlaying with an opacity less than `0.1`.

```
var cvas = document.getElementById("ctxt"),
    cx = cvas.getContext("2d"),
    lFade = new Date(),
    lBox = new Date(),
    lClear = new Date();

function randomColor(num) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
}

(function draw(){
    var now = new Date();

    if (now - lFade > 20){
        cx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.025)"
        cx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        lFade = now;
    }
    if (now - lClear > 800){
        cx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"
        cx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        lClear = now;
    }

    if (now - lBox > 200){
        var r = randomColor(255);
        var g = randomColor(255);
        var b = randomColor(255);
        cx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ",1.0)";
        cx.fillRect(200*Math.random(), 200*Math.random(), 300*Math.random(), 300*Math.random());
        lBox = now;
    }

    setTimeout(draw, 1000/60);
})();
```

Comment: Hmm, I see what you did there..But unfortunately, it is still (almost) the same since it does not fade out to full white  ----

Also, if I increase the opacity to get the effect faster, it still "jumps" between fades... :(

Comment: @Zettam it's fading to full white for me (albeit sitting at that light gray for a bit) in Chrome.

Comment: @Zettam You could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/pUVkA/35/ But it flickers a little bit.

Comment: Thank you for the new fiddle as well. However, it does not fade to full white in my case...
Also, I want the transition to be WEEEY more slow (it will be transformed to full-white from creation in around 5 minutes) so I will be needing a lot less opacity for the white layer to overcome the "stepped" look....